# Global logging to file in a Java application

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, java.util.logging

I have a swing application that requires some logging capabilities. I would like to log all global issues to a log file somewhere on the system.

I started off with setting up my logger in my `main`:

```
// Setup global logging.
Logger.getLogger("").addHandler(new FileHandler("%t/log.txt"));
```

I understand that the `%t` denotes the temporary directory, but when I'm working in Netbeans, where is this directory located on a Windows machine? Where would the file be located when running standalone (e.g. outside of Netbeans)? Is there a better alternative such as placing the file in `My Documents` or something similar? Is creating a log file in a `temp` directory standard practice?

Also, is leaving the name of the logger `""` common practice for a global logger or should I be using the most general package (e.g. `com.some.package`)?

Now, when I go to actually log something to the file I can simply make the following calls, correct?

`Logger.getLogger("").log(Level.SEVERE, msg, ex);`

Any advice on best practices would be much appreciated.

Comment: If you use the classname as the logger's root, you can control log filtering based on package and for specific classes so it does pay off to create loggers that way, yes. Example: you could configure that for package 'x.y.z' you log only errors and not warnings/info messages. And no, it is not common practice to log to a temp directory. I'd log to a configurable folder myself and by default make it the directory that the application is running in. That's a personal opinion.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the temp folder location you can do:

```
System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir"));
```

Also, logging with java util logger is inferior due to many reasons to other logging mechanisms like [logback](http://logback.qos.ch/), [slf4j](http://www.slf4j.org/) and [log4j](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/), so I suggest you start using one of those loggers.

Comment: All of my logging will be relatively straightforward. That's why I didn't look at any alternatives such as log4j.

Comment: From performance perspective, other logging frameworks, especially slf4j/logback and log4j2 offer many improvements over java.util logging. Also, they are tons more configurable. In my career as a java developer I have yet to see an app that relies on java.util logging as main logging algorithm. You are better off using http://projectlombok.org/, adding the @Slf4j annotation to your class and be done with it.

Answer (score 0):

You should create the logger and add your handler in a singleton class.  From the java doc:

Logger objects may be obtained by calls on one of the getLogger factory methods. These will either create a new Logger or return a suitable existing Logger. It is important to note that the Logger returned by one of the getLogger factory methods may be garbage collected at any time if a strong reference to the Logger is not kept.

That means the logger may be garbage collected and your file handler will be lost.

As for file location, why don't you create a logs directory beneath in folder that your jar is located?